# Jenkins maven-release-plugin -D properties using in the pom

Tags: maven, jenkins, maven-release-plugin

How to use `-D` argument in the `pom.xml` when performing a release in Jenkins?
`mvn --help` say:

```
-D,--define <arg>                      Define a system property
```

But if I use `-D` property as system variable, `sys.someProperty`, it is not visible.

Example: `pom.xml`:
...

```
<properties>
    <jira.password>${sys.password}</jira.password>
</properties>
```

Command:

```
mvn -B -f pom.xml -DdevelopmentVersion=2.5-SNAPSHOT -DreleaseVersion=2.4 -Dusername=ivan -Dresume=false release:prepare release:perform -Dpassword=*********
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you are using the [`maven-release-plugin`](http://maven.apache.org/maven-release/maven-release-plugin/), the system arguments must be written in the [`arguments`](http://maven.apache.org/maven-release/maven-release-plugin/prepare-mojo.html#arguments) system property. This is because the release is performed in a forked Maven instance so system properties set before are lost.

Example to skip the tests during release:

```
mvn -B release:prepare -Darguments="-DskipTests=true"
```

Comment: How do this with jenkins maven release plugin?

Comment: @burtsevyg in the release plugin, you just need to modify your current command that is executed to use `-Darguments`

Comment: jenkins maven release plugin asking password when performing release in command it not present

Comment: @burtsevyg It's unclear what you're saying. What password? I was refering to your `sys.password` property. This is the one that should be in `-Darguments`

Comment: I cannot change -Dpassword=******* to -Darguments="-Dpassword=*******" because this argument added jenkins maven release plugin to release command

Comment: @burtsevyg But that is not what you should change. What you should change is `-Dsys.password=...` to `-Darguments="-Dsys.password=..."`.

Comment: Sorry, but I need scm username and password http://maven.apache.org/maven-release/maven-release-plugin/prepare-mojo.html#username

Comment: I think that I can get it how system variable.

Comment: I use ldap for authorization in jira, git and others

Comment: Why I can not simple use username and password in my pom.xml?

Comment: I don't understand your problem here and I'm really lost. The SCM username and SCM password are rightfully given as `-Dusername` and `-Dpassword`. However, every other system variable, like `jira.password` needs to be under `-Darguments`.

Comment: Ok. May I use this variables, username and password in release build but not in scm plugin? If I try use it the build failed, but if I point username and password in settings.xml build successful.

Comment: Username and passwords can be given as command line parameters, like said before. You can also set them in the settings.xml yes. If you give the username and password as `-Dusername` and `-Dpassword` it should work.

Comment: -D properties not accessible in the pom.xml

Comment: when I performing release